# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am getting bellow error recently my currently using app. when try to insert record using eloquent.
This code was perfectly working in past few months. Now it just throwing the error after '1303' records inserted.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du
>   champ '1304' pour la clef 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `orderrequest`
>
> Translate from: English SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1062 Duplicate field '1304' for the 'PRIMARY' key (SQL:
>   insert into orderrequest

```
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $order = OrderModel::find($id);
    $kot = new OrderrequestModel;
    $kot->orid = $id;
    $kot->location = $order->location;
    $kot->provider = "kitchen";

    $orderitems =OrderitemModel::where('orid', '=', $id)->get();
    $total = 0;


    foreach ($orderitems as $orderitem) {
        //$total = $total+($orderitem->price * $orderitem->qty);
        if($orderitem->provider=="kitchen"){
    $kot->token .= '<tr>
            <td align="left">'.$orderitem->fiid.'</td>
            <td align="left">'.$orderitem->item.'</td>
            <td align="center">'.$orderitem->provider.'</td>
            <td align="center">'.$orderitem->qty.'</td>

          </tr>';
          $orderitem->isreq = "k";
          $orderitem->save();
        }
    }
    $kot->token .= '</table>';
    $kot->type = "full";
    $kot->save();
```

Comment: you probably already have a record corresponding to same `primary id` in your table.

Comment: the curent PRIMARY key is 1303.

Comment: Check whether your `primary_key` is not `auto incrimantal`

Comment: it is AUTO_INCREMENT and this code work perfectly over  1300 records.

Comment: id
mediumint(9)
AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: @Kombuwa As `Nitesh Verma` told, there might already be the data with your `id = 1304`.

Comment: @Kombuwa Also it would be great if you show us your table schema and your rows having the value `1304`.

Comment: no only maximum value is id =  1303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t know reason but after I have change the Type from mediumint(9) to int(11) now code is perfectly working. If you know the reason for this please comment bellow

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you are trying to insert into the database. Laravel writes that your primary key already exists in the database.

In the model, the primary key OrderitemModel orid?
Did you write the data again.

Use OrderitemModel::findOrNew($orid)

Comment: in OrderitemModel primary key is just 'id'. and orid is just foreign key